# How to relate react native ToolbarAndroid with Navigator

Tags: react-native

I would like to know a way to relate ToolbarAndroid with the Navigator component. My intention is always to show the **route.title** in a ToolbarAndroid child, such as a Text component. This way, if a use the **BackAndroid** component, my title is always up to date! I don't want to use Navigator.NavigationBar because I would miss the overflow menu built in on the ToolbarAndroid.

Appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
//... some code before

render() {
  return(
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid
      drawerWidth={300}
      ref={(drawerElement) => { this.DRAWER = drawerElement; }}
      drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.left}
      onDrawerOpen={this.setDrawerState}
      onDrawerClose={this.setDrawerState}
      renderNavigationView={() => <DrawerMenu navigate={this.navigateTo} />}
    >
      <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
        titleColor='#fff'
        navIconName='md-menu'
        onIconClicked={this.toggleDrawer}
        actions={toolbarActions}
        onActionSelected={this._onActionSelected}
        style={styles.appBar}
        overflowIconName="md-more"
      >
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.navigateTo.bind(this, 0)}
            style={styles.appBarLogo}
          >
            <Icon name="md-boat" size={30} color="#fff" />
            <Text
              style={styles.appBarTitle}
              numberOfLines={1}
            >
              {this.state.title}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Icon.ToolbarAndroid>
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={routes[0]}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
          switch (route.index) {
            case 0:
              return <Home />
            case 1:
              return <Lindau />;
            case 2:
              return <About />;
            case 3:
              return <Credits />;
            default:
              return <Home />;
          }
        }}
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>
          Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
        }
        ref={(nav) => { this._navigator = nav; }}
      />
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, please, help me if anyone has a better solution for this. After several attempts, I figured out one possible solution.

I created a state for my component called 'routes', then, I've set up my Toolbar title with this state. Basically, this state is a stack of my routes. When I change my scene, I push this route in my state, when I back from BackAndroid component, I pop out the route from the state, and everything works fine.

Here the code fixed:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      routes: [0], // Here the state to fix the problem...
      drawerClosed: true,
    }
    this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this);
    this._onActionSelected = this._onActionSelected.bind(this);
    this.navigateTo = this.navigateTo.bind(this);
    this.setDrawerState = this.setDrawerState.bind(this);
    this.handlesBackButton = this.handlesBackButton.bind(this);
  }

  navigateTo(idx) {
    this.setState({
      routes: [ ...this.state.routes, idx]
    });
    this.DRAWER.closeDrawer();
    if (idx === 0) {
      this._navigator.resetTo(routes[0]);
      this.setState({
        routes: [0]
      });
    } else {
      this._navigator.push(routes[idx]);
    }
  }

  handlesBackButton() {
    if (this._navigator && this._navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
      try {
        this._navigator.jumpBack();
        const _routes = this.state.routes.slice();
        _routes.pop();
        this.setState({
          routes: _routes
        });
      } catch(e) {}
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        ref={(drawerElement) => { this.DRAWER = drawerElement; }}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.left}
        onDrawerOpen={this.setDrawerState}
        onDrawerClose={this.setDrawerState}
        renderNavigationView={() => <DrawerMenu navigate={this.navigateTo} />}
      >
        <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
          titleColor='#fff'
          navIconName='md-menu'
          onIconClicked={this.toggleDrawer}
          actions={toolbarActions}
          onActionSelected={this._onActionSelected}
          style={styles.appBar}
          overflowIconName="md-more"
        >
          <View style={styles.appBarLogo}> // I have to fix this component view...
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this.navigateTo.bind(this, 0)}
            >
              <Icon name="md-boat" size={30} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text
              style={styles.appBarTitle}
              numberOfLines={1}
            >
              {routes[this.state.routes[this.state.routes.length - 1]].title}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Icon.ToolbarAndroid>
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={routes[0]}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
            switch (route.index) {
              case 0:
                return <Home />;
              case 1:
                return <Lindau />;
              case 2:
                return <About />;
              case 3:
                return <Credits />;
              default:
                return <Home />;
            }
          }}
          configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>
            Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
          }
          ref={(nav) => { this._navigator = nav; }}
        />
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }

}
```